# Need Help About Parse Multi Level JSON

Tags: javascript, html

My JSON Data

```
var verses = '[{"ChapterNumber":1,"Verses":[{"VersesNumber":1,"Verses":"Text Come here 1"},{"VersesNumber":2,"Verses":"Text Come here 2"},{"VersesNumber":3,"Verses":"Text Come here 3"},{"VersesNumber":4,"Verses":"Text Come here 4"},{"VersesNumber":5,"Verses":"Text Come here 5"},{"VersesNumber":6,"Verses":"Text Come here 6"},{"VersesNumber":7,"Verses":"Text Come here 7"},{"VersesNumber":8,"Verses":"Text Come here 8"},{"VersesNumber":9,"Verses":"Text Come here 9"},{"VersesNumber":10,"Verses":"Text Come here 10"},{"VersesNumber":11,"Verses":"Text Come here 11"},{"VersesNumber":12,"Verses":"Text Come here 12"},{"VersesNumber":13,"Verses":"Text Come here 13"},{"VersesNumber":14,"Verses":"Text Come here 14"},{"VersesNumber":15,"Verses":"Text Come here 15"},{"VersesNumber":16,"Verses":"Text Come here 16"},{"VersesNumber":17,"Verses":"Text Come here 17"},{"VersesNumber":18,"Verses":"Text Come here 18"},{"VersesNumber":19,"Verses":"Text Come here 19"},{"VersesNumber":20,"Verses":"Text Come here 20"},{"VersesNumber":21,"Verses":"Text Come here 21"},{"VersesNumber":22,"Verses":"Text Come here 22"},{"VersesNumber":23,"Verses":"Text Come here 23"},{"VersesNumber":24,"Verses":"Text Come here 24"},{"VersesNumber":25,"Verses":"Text Come here 25"}]}]'
```

I try JSON.Parse

```
var Obj = JSON.parse(verses);
for (var i = 0; i < Obj.length; i++) {
    if (Obj[i].ChapterNumber === ChapterNumber) {
        console.log(Obj[i].ChapterNumber);
    }
}
```

this work very good to get the first Node
but it can't get the second node or thereed node
i try this also as test code

```
console.log(Obj[i].ChapterNumber.Verses)
```

but with no success any one can give me a hint please.

Comment: What's your expected output, please? Seems like it's parsing fine (this is an array with a single object element in it, not an object), so it seems like `arr[0].Verses[i]` should be sufficient.

Comment: `Verses` is not a child property of the `ChapterNumber`.  It's a sibling property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let chapter = '[{"ChapterNumber":1,"Verses":[{"VersesNumber":1,"Verses":"Text Come here 1"},{"VersesNumber":2,"Verses":"Text Come here 2"},{"VersesNumber":3,"Verses":"Text Come here 3"},{"VersesNumber":4,"Verses":"Text Come here 4"},{"VersesNumber":5,"Verses":"Text Come here 5"},{"VersesNumber":6,"Verses":"Text Come here 6"},{"VersesNumber":7,"Verses":"Text Come here 7"},{"VersesNumber":8,"Verses":"Text Come here 8"},{"VersesNumber":9,"Verses":"Text Come here 9"},{"VersesNumber":10,"Verses":"Text Come here 10"},{"VersesNumber":11,"Verses":"Text Come here 11"},{"VersesNumber":12,"Verses":"Text Come here 12"},{"VersesNumber":13,"Verses":"Text Come here 13"},{"VersesNumber":14,"Verses":"Text Come here 14"},{"VersesNumber":15,"Verses":"Text Come here 15"},{"VersesNumber":16,"Verses":"Text Come here 16"},{"VersesNumber":17,"Verses":"Text Come here 17"},{"VersesNumber":18,"Verses":"Text Come here 18"},{"VersesNumber":19,"Verses":"Text Come here 19"},{"VersesNumber":20,"Verses":"Text Come here 20"},{"VersesNumber":21,"Verses":"Text Come here 21"},{"VersesNumber":22,"Verses":"Text Come here 22"},{"VersesNumber":23,"Verses":"Text Come here 23"},{"VersesNumber":24,"Verses":"Text Come here 24"},{"VersesNumber":25,"Verses":"Text Come here 25"}]}]'
chapter = JSON.parse(chapter);
for (var i = 0; i < chapter.length; i++) {
    console.log('Chapter number: '+chapter[i].ChapterNumber);
    for (var n = 0; n < chapter[i].Verses.length; n++) {
        let verse = chapter[i].Verses[n];
        console.log('Verse number: '+verse.VersesNumber);
        console.log('Verse: '+verse.Verses);
    }
}
```